# auto install/copy files to someone's system

Tags: c#, html, css, vb.net, window

let me give a example that what i want to do:

i have friend i send an email(etc link) to my friend when he/she open my email and clicked (etc link) ...
at this point i want to  copy a program without he/she knows that a program has been copied to his/her system 
can i anyone plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is called [malicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) and generally isn't allowed by OS and/or antivirus software. Any workarounds passing the protection would be [exploitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) of an vulnerability.

> Malware is defined by its malicious intent, acting against the requirements of the computer user

Also, it is illegal.

Comment: i want to use this on pc not android

Comment: please help me dude this is my last stage of project and i cant fine anything i want when user click some link i send him/her a program should be auto install/or copy to his/her system

Comment: Why just don't make a proper installer?

Comment: its kind a secret type if you what i mean
without anyone know i want to install this

Comment: So it actually is a malicious intent. It is illegal and unethical.

Comment: if you ask me i think its unethical if you observe many time when use google to download somthing add shows up very annoying and the worst part when click an add (mostly) some anonymous files also download

Comment: if you notices this i want to do just like if i had a link and user clicked the link some programes automatic download to its system

Comment: There is a big difference between downloading, say, cookies and executing unwanted binaries. You want these files to be executed by remote system, not just downloaded. Moreover, you want to do this against user's will. That's exactly how malware works.

Comment: yeah u are rite i'll search more will study about malware i dont know what this is or it's wiki

Answer (score -1):

You can try reinstalling the .net framework again in your system .
You can download the framework from microsoft website .